# Appending Text on the Line Below a Regular Expression Match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to add text that reads "[value = xxx]" below every line that contains the word "Letters" and also append a comma to the line containing the word "Letters" and I thought using a Regular Expression in Notepad++ would work but I can't quite figure it out. Also, matches are not spaced regularly (ie. It's not as simple as adding "[value = xxx]" to every 3rd row).

What I have currently looks like:

```
Properties = "_2nastlsgb",
     Letters = "#,S"
textline2
textline3
Properties = "_1,N",
     Letters = "A"
```

I would like for the end result to be something like:

```
Properties = "_2nastlsgb",
     Letters = "#,S",
     [value = xxx]
textline2
textline3
Properties = "_1,N",
     Letters = "A",
     [value = xxx]
```

I'm really close with the following but it ends up just a bit off:
Find What: letter(.*)
Replace with: \1,\n\t\t\t\t[Value = ###]

Result:

```
 Properties = "_2nastlsgb",
         s = "#,S",
                [Value = ###]
    textline2
    textline3
    Properties = "_1,N",
         s = "A",
                [Value = ###]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
^(.*?)(Letters.*)
```

And replace with:

```
$1$2,\n$1[Value = ###]
```

This regex will take the indent of the `Letters` and apply it to the `Value` as well.

The issue with your regex was that it was replacing `letter` and not placing it back, thus the lone `s`.